# C# generic inheritance and covariance

Tags: c#, generics

I'm building a collection library and I'd like to have all the generic collection interfaces require class types and all the collections implementing them to be any type.  So on value types the collection would have two methods, one for the value type and one for boxing it.  Is this possible?

Like this:

```
interface ICollection<ItemType> where ItemType : class
{
    void DoSomething(ItemType item);
}

class Collection<ItemType> : ICollection<ItemType>
{
    void DoSomething(Object item);
    void DoSomething(ItemType item);
}
```

Barring that what would be the best way to get around it?  The interfaces being non-generic?

Comment: Why? One of the big wins with generics (if unrestricted) is that they work with value types and avoid boxing.

Comment: Well when someone uses the interface for a collection, they're really expecting that you can work with it as a reference type and inheritence will work on it.  This needs to work:  ICollection<Object> s = new Collection<String>();

Comment: @Ryan why should that work? That doesn't work for any other collection: why would they expect it for yours? *Especially* when there is a value-type involved (variance doesn't slide between value-type and reference-type)

Comment: `s.Add(new FruitBat());` just added something that's not a string to your collection of strings.

Comment: Your interface has a method `DoSomething` that takes **in** an `ItemType` (which I'll rename `TItem`). Therefore it would be illegal to mark the interface covariant ("out") as in `interface ICollection<out TItem>`.

Comment: Can you get from a collection of Strings to a collection of Objects without copying the entire collection?  That's not really very good.  Good point on the invalid type thing but that is testable in the add method... maybe.

Comment: Hmm a lot to think on, thanks for the feedback guys, it helps a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
ICollection<Object> s = new Collection<String>();
```

(comments) would work with `out` variance; however, `DoSomething(ItemType)` would require `in` variance; so that type can be neither `in` nor `out`: variance *does not apply here*.

The way that is usually handled is by having a generic *and* non-generic API. People interested in the specific types can use the generic API; people just interested in "an object" can use the non-generic API.

For illustration:

```
interface ICollection
{
    void DoSomething(object item);
}
interface ICollection<ItemType> : ICollection
{
    void DoSomething(ItemType item);
}

class Collection<ItemType> : ICollection<ItemType>
{
    void ICollection.DoSomething(Object item)
    {
        DoSomething((ItemType)item);
    }
    public void DoSomething(ItemType item)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then *this* works:

```
ICollection s = new Collection<String>();
object o = "abcd";
s.DoSomething(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Value types are always boxed as type `object`. That would force a collection of any boxed value type to be a `Collection<object>`, which is not really typesafe (noone prevents you from adding e.g. a `string`, then). Type safety is meant to be one of the biggest advantages of generic types though. So I would suggest dropping the `class` constraint, if possible.

BTW: You can still assign these generic interfaces (without `class` constraint) to their non-generic version:
`IList l = new List<int>();`

Comment: I believe jitter produces different code for `List<int>` and `List<string>`, and `int`s aren't stored in `List` as boxed.

Comment: @Joker_vD Yes, but i was talking about collections of *boxed* value types. Edited answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah, you meant to say that "When values are boxed, they are not turned into instances of some special `Integer` or `Double` classes designed specially to hold boxed values (there are no such classes, unlike Java), but end up being just `object`s", am I right? Okay, sorry for misreading.

Comment: @Joker_vD Yes, actually i also thought about java's wrapper types, but didn't include them in the answer ^^