# C# generic inheritance and covariance part 2

Tags: c#, generics

Here is my original thread:
[C# generic inheritance and covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252872/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance)

On just my read-only interfaces, I want inheritence to work.

```
public delegate Boolean EnumerateItemsDelegate<out ItemType>(ItemType item);

public interface IReadOnlyCollection<out ItemType>
{
    Boolean ContainsItem(ItemType item);
    Array CopyToArray();
    void EnumerateItems(EnumerateItemsDelegate<ItemType> enumerateDelegate);

    UInt32 Count { get; }
    UInt32 Capacity { get; }
}
```

Like this except where it compiles :-p

This is what I would like to work:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<String> s;
IReadOnlyCollection<Object> o = s;
```

Comment: BTW, `ItemType` should be called `T`.

Comment: Rather than having `CopyToArray` return an `Array`, have it return `ItemType[]`, so that it's strongly typed.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any question in this question. "I want inheritance to work" is not a question. Rewrite this as a question if you want an answer. The compiler is correct; this code is not typesafe.

Comment: Servy that would be nice but then inheritance on the interface wouldn't work.  Would be nice to be able to do that too.  I edited the question to be clearer what I want to do.

Comment: @Eric what is unsafe about it?

Comment: First problem: `in T` creates a contravariant interface, so if it compiled, you could assign an `IReadOnlyCollection<object>` to an `IReadOnlyCollection<string>`, but not the other way round.

Comment: Second problem: You can't compile with `in T` because you're passing the values `out` via the delegate.

Comment: Third problem: You can't compile with `out T` because you're passing the values `in` via the `ContainsItem` method.

Comment: @SLaks: According to [Microsoft's coding guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.100).aspx) `ItemType` should be **prefixed** with `T`: `TItemType`

Comment: Guess I really wanted to use 'out'.  Is it possible to tell the compiler that 'Boolean ContainsItem(ItemType item);' doesn't care what type it is if it's a reference type?

Comment: What's unsafe is that you can use your code to completely break the type system! The compiler knows that and therefore disallows it. See my answer for details.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's not possible since the compiler always assumes you're using the type info even if you're not

Comment: Well I really do appreciate the feedback even if I do get voted down and mocked just for trying something new to make it better for everybody...

Comment: @RyanBrown: The question is being voted down because it is a poorly asked question. It's extremely unclear what you're asking because there is no actual question in it, it shows little evidence that you've done any research, and your accepted answer rate is extremely low. If you really want to make things better for everyone then do your research, ask clear questions, and accept good answers.

Comment: Inheritance working on generic read only collection interfaces is really pretty self explanatory...  You could clearly see what I'm trying to accomplish with the code there.  It WOULD work with a language that supported compile-time only generics.  I just wanted to see if it was possible in C#

Comment: Reading your question again: I also think you maybe are using the word "inheritance" to mean "assignment compatibility". Inheritance is a relationship between two types whereby heritable members of an ancestor type are automatically members of the descendant type. Assignment compatibility is a relationship between the type associated with a unit of storage and the type associated with a value. It's important to not confuse these two quite different concepts.

Comment: Good point!  Thanks I didn't think about that.

Comment: @RyanBrown If you want to maintain covariance while still having a `ContainsItem` method, try this signature: `bool ContainsItem<T>(T item) where T : ItemType;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There does not appear to be any question in this question, so I'll make up a few questions to answer.

> What is a covariant conversion?

Let's suppose we have some types `Fruit` and `Apple` and `Banana` with the obvious relationships; `Apple` is a kind of `Fruit`, and so on.

A covariant conversion is one where the convertability of the type argument implies the convertibility of the generic type. If `Apple` is convertible to `Fruit`, and `Bowl<Apple>` is convertible to `Bowl<Fruit>`, then `Bowl<T>` is covariant in T.

---

> What is a contravariant conversion?

A contravariant conversion is a covariant conversion that *reverses* the direction instead of *preserving* it. If `Eater<Fruit>` is convertible to `Eater<Apple>` then `Eater<T>` is contravariant in T.

---

> How do I mark an interface or delegate as being covariant or contravariant in its type parameters?

Covariant type parameters are marked `out` and contravariant type parameters are marked `in`.

This is intended to be mnemonic: covariant interfaces typically have the type parameter appear in output positions and contravariant interfaces typeically have the type parameter appear in input positions.

---

> `String` is convertible to `Object`. How can I make `IReadOnlyCollection<String>` convertible to `IReadOnlyCollection<Object>`?

Make `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` covariant in T. Mark it `out`.

---

> Consider the following code:

```
delegate void Action<in T>(T t);
interface IFoo<in X>
{
  void M(Action<X> action);
}
```

> Why does the compiler say that this is not valid?

Because it is not valid. Let's see why.

```
class Foo : IFoo<Fruit>
{
  public void M(Action<Fruit> action)
  {
     action(new Apple()); // An apple is a fruit.
  }
}
...
IFoo<Fruit> iff = new Foo();
IFoo<Banana> ifb = iff; // Contravariant!
ifb.M(banana => { banana.Peel(); });
```

Follow the logic. This program passes an apple as the "this" of `Banana.Peel()`, which is clearly wrong.

The compiler knows that this can happen, and so disallows the interface to be declared in the first place.

---

> What should I do if I have more questions about variance?

You should start by reading my articles on the design and implementation of the feature. Start from the bottom; they are listed in reverse chronological order:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/

If you still have a question then you should post questions here that actually contain questions, instead of making people guess what the question really is.

Comment: You're right I really wanted out, now just to tell the compiler that ContainsItem doesn't care about the type as long as it's a reference type...

Comment: @RyanBrown See my comment above.  To tell the compiler you "don't care" about the type of the parameter to the `ContainsItem` method, make it of a new generic type which inherits from `ItemType` as follows: `bool ContainsItem<T>(T item) where T : ItemType;`.