# C#, how to Cast Action<List<T>> to Action<List<object>>

Tags: c#

I am working on a function of an indie game, which used to take in `Action<List<Character>>` as a parameter to display the Characters' info. Now I have decided that players can mod the game, so the display system can display anything else than just Characters.
I've overloaded the new display function, which now takes in `Action<List<object>>` as a parameter. The old function is still being  used by the "Character" specific displays, and it would just pass `Action<List<Character>>` to the new overloaded one, but I have no idea how to cast `Action<List<Character>>` to `Action<List<object>>`.
Any help would be appreciated. I'm aware there is an alternative, which is to change all my old `Action<List<Character>>` to `Action<List<object>>`, and then cast `List<object>` to `List<Character>`.

Comment: "_I have no idea how to cast `Action<List<Character>>` to `Action<List<object>>`_" - You can't. Nothing to do with `Action<T>` though, it's because `List<T>` is invariant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# generic inheritance and covariance part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2) and [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase/58783084#58783084)

Comment: You cannot cast, but you implement one based on the other, e.g. `actionOnListOfObjects = (Action<List<object>>)(list => actionOnListOfCharacters(list.Cast<Character>().ToList())`

Comment: The problem is that users can *modify* the list that you pass in -- they can add items. If you pass in a `List<object>`, then can any type of object at all. If your list can actually only contain `Characters`, that's a problem.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast) if the code lends itself to it.