# How to create at runtime, from an enum value, a List of subclass, and get the closed generic type relevant to the subclass, as a List of base class?

Tags: c#, list, generics, polymorphism, subclass

I'm actually trying to solve a problem with List in C#.

Here are my classes:

```
public class  A {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
}

public class B1 : A {
    public int info { get; set; }
}
public class B2 : A {
    public C info { get; set; }
}
public class C {
   ...
}
```

I would like to have a function like that:

```
public List<A> function(typeEnum t)
```

To be able to return an object instance of type `List<B1>` or `List<B2>` and so on, depending on the requested `typeEnum`, as a `List<A>`.

My problem is the different type of `info` in `B1` and `B2` classes.

Comment: What is `typeEnum`? Would something like `List<T> function<T>()` work? Then you could call `var listOfB1 = function<B1>()`

Comment: Do you want a list of instances, or do you want types? Your `function` returns instances.

Comment: typeEnum is an enum, it help me to chose if I return B1 or B2 List.

Comment: I want a list of instances, I've tryied to use <T> but it does not work.

Comment: Are those new instances, or already-existing instances that you want?

Comment: They are B1 and B2 instances

Comment: Note that you cannot assign a List<Derived> type to a variable with a type of List<Base>. For the reason, consider: Given base `List<Mammal>` and derived `List<Cat>` and `List<Dog>`. If you could  do `List<Mammal> mlist = myListOfDogs;` then you could do `mlist.Add(new Cat());` and chaos would ensue as you've added a Cat to a list of Dog!

Comment: They are different because the type of "info" is different in B1 and B2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new object instance from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/how-to-create-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type) and [How to dynamically create a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class)

Comment: That doesn't help me sorry

Comment: @hcurtillet [True generic polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247604/how-to-do-generic-polymorphism-on-open-types-in-c/58247676#58247676) is not yet available in C# since we don't have the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/how-to-create-list-of-open-generic-type-of-classt/58571001#58571001) working for that, thus you can't return either a `List<B1>` or `List<B2>` as `List<A>`, sorry. You only can return `List<A>` where you can put any child. Else *you need as many method as many expected returned types*.

Comment: @hcurtillet  See also [C# generic inheritance and covariance part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2/14264436#14264436) and [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase/58783084)

Comment: @hcurtillet Concerning the problem about `info`, can you add more details on how it will be used. Perhaps you can use `dynamic`, or not... I think rather of a generic `B<T> : A` to have `T info`.

Comment: Your issue is that List<> is not covarient (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)  using IEnumerable is more plausibly if you do not want to subsequently alter what is in the List

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is unclear (hence the comments), what you might be searching for is a LINQ extension.

```cs
var list_of_a = new List<A>{ new A(), new B1(), new B1(), new B2(), new C() };
var list_of_b = list_of_a.OfType<B1>();
```

where list_of_b only contains the elements that are of B1.

Comment: No sorry that's not what I'm looking for. The problem is the return fo my function, I lost the "info" instance because it's not is A.

Comment: Well, as B1 inherrits from A, they are all A. And you can add .Cast<A> if you need A in your contract. But down-voting someone who tries to help you on a bad defined question is... well not that encouraging...

Comment: the info property of type int belongs to B1, and info property of type C belongs to B2. The result of `list_of_a.OfType<B1>();` would return you a list of B1 objects, and these objects would have the info property, as well as ID and Tag from the A they derive from

Answer (score -1):

You could have a switch-case to do the OfType for you based on the typeEnum:

```
public List<A> function(typeEnum t, List<A> listToFilter)
{
    switch (t)
    {
        case typeEnum.B1:
            return listToFilter.OfType<B1>().ToList();

        case typeEnum.B2:
            return listToFilter.OfType<B2>().ToList();

        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Please implement " + t);
    }

}
```

Or you can use a Linq Where function to filter.
If your typeEnum values match the name of the type you are filtering by, you could do something like:

```
public List<A> function(typeEnum t, List<A> listToFilter)
{
    return listToFilter.Where(item => item.GetType().Name == t.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

In both cases, you'll need to cast the items in the returned list to have access to the 'info' property as they'll be returned as 'A' objects, but they are still instances of the type you filtered on.