# Dynamic generic class in list

Tags: c#, generics

Hi I want to make a list of generic class objects, but T of the generic class is dynamic.
For example, I want to make a list which can contain `SomeClass<int>, SomeClass<string>, SomeClass<char>` etc...

```
class SomeClass<T>{}

List<SomeClass<dynamic>> list = new List<SomeClass<dynamic>>();
list.Add(new SomeClass<int>()); //CS1503 : cannot convert from 'SomeClass<int>' to 'SomeClass<dynamic>'
list.Add(new SomeClass<string>()); //CS1503 : cannot convert from 'SomeClass<string>' to 'SomeClass<dynamic>'
list.Add(new SomeClass<char>()); //CS1503 : cannot convert from 'SomeClass<char>' to 'SomeClass<dynamic>'
```

Comment: Maybe have a base class `SomeClass` and have `SomeClass<T>` derive from it or an `ISomeClass` interface that `SomeClass<T>` implements. That way, your list could be `List<SomeClass>` or `List<ISomeClass>`.

Comment: The only types in C# that can unify `SomeClass<T>` for an unconstrained `T` are `object` and `dynamic`. Note: not `SomeClass<dynamic>`; at runtime this is just `SomeClass<object>`, and since reference-type generics and value-type generics have different representations, classes like `SomeClass<int>` and `SomeClass<string>` fundamentally can't be treated as the same type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create List of open generic type of class<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/how-to-create-list-of-open-generic-type-of-classt) and [How to do generic polymorphism on open types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247604/how-to-do-generic-polymorphism-on-open-types-in-c/)

Comment: [C# generic inheritance and covariance part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2/14264436#14264436)