# Why is using a variable of a generic interface with a concrete class instance inheriting the interface fail in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

Given these interfaces and classes

```
public interface IFoo { }

public interface IFooWrapper<I> where I : IFoo { }

public class Foo : IFoo { }
public class FooWrapper : IFooWrapper<Foo> { }
```

Why does this fail?

```
IFooWrapper<IFoo> foo = new FooWrapper();
```

I know I could use `dynamic`, here, but the real question is : I have a method that would receive an implementation of these interfaces, and it fails for the same reason :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'FooWrapper' to 'IFooWrapper'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The method signature would look like

```
void Register(IFooWrapper<IFoo> foo)
{
}
```

The compiler fails at the line

```
Register(new FooWrapper());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# generic inheritance and covariance part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2) (and [About the lack of true generic polymorphism and the missing diamond operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/how-to-create-list-of-open-generic-type-of-classt/58571001#58571001))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because of co- and contra-variance.

When something is a `IFooWrapper<Foo>`, that doesn't mean it's could be compile time converted to `IFooWrapper<IFoo>`. I think it's better explained here: [Covariance and Contravariance (C#) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) and [still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out).

Please note that you could mark interfaces in C# as co- or contra-variant. For example, if you have the below interface (notice the `out I` - it's now covariant for type parameter `I`), you could use `IFooWrapper<IFoo> foo = new FooWrapper();`

```
public interface IFooWrapper<out I> where I : IFoo { }
```

See demo in [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/An0XtA)

Instead of changing the interface, you could fix the method signature with generics:

```
void Register<T>(IFooWrapper<T> foo) where T: IFoo
{
}
```

That one could be called with `IFooWrapper<Foo>` and `IFooWrapper<IFoo>` - so this works: `Register(new FooWrapper());`

See also [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sSaIn8)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It works as well. Cheers!